# How to dispatch an event in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8, email-verification

I am manually implementing user registration within my application and I have failed to understand this section of laravel 8 docs

> If you are manually implementing registration within your application instead of using a starter kit, you should ensure that you are dispatching the Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered event after a user's registration is successful:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

event(new Registered($user));
```

I tried different approaches but in the end i failed to understand this and email is not being sent
Here is my registration code
public function storeUser(Request $request){

```
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email'  => 'required|email:rfc,dns',
            'password' => ['required','confirmed', Password::min(8)],
            'phone_number' => 'required'
            
        ]);
        
        $registeredDetails = User::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number
        ]);
        
        
}
```

My question is where do I dispatch this event the documentation is saying?

Here is the top of my UserControler

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
```

and here is the mail code in env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=kokayazanzibar.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=demo@kokayazanzibar.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=ienteredmypasswordhere
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=demo@kokayazanzibar.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Here is EventServiceProvider

```
    class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not implement the interface on my User Model.
It was

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
```

I thought I put it well but I was missing this implementation and was supposed to be like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
    {
```

and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

You would dispatch this after the user is created in your application.

In your case:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email'  => 'required|email:rfc,dns',
    'password' => ['required','confirmed', Password::min(8)],
    'phone_number' => 'required'        
]);
        
$registeredDetails = User::create([
    'first_name' => $request->first_name,
    'last_name' => $request->last_name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    'phone_number' => $request->phone_number
]);
    
event(new Registered($registeredDetails));
```

Comment: I actually tried this and the email was not sent so I had a doubt maybe this was not a correct way to trigger the event sending the email

Comment: @alphillips do you have a listener setup to send the email?

Comment: Is there any other listener i need to setup apart form what the documentation says  "Once this interface has been added to your model, newly registered users will automatically be sent an email containing an email verification link. As you can see by examining your application's App\Providers\EventServiceProvider, Laravel already contains a SendEmailVerificationNotification listener that is attached to the Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered event. This event listener will send the email verification link to the user."

Comment: @alphillips no. That’s the right event. Do you have that setup? And is your mail config correct in your env file

Comment: I just edited my post and included it, would you please take a look again?

Comment: @alphillips what does the send email listener look like? Is it queued at all?

Comment: Do you mean the one found in App\Providers\EventServiceProvider ?